# Span command across LaTeX environments

Tags: environments

Suppose I have an environment `redacted` which I wanted to declare in such a manner:

```
\begin{redacted}
This is some secret content.
\end{redacted}
```

Which, I wanted the result to be equivalent to passing the text inside the environment inside `minipage` and `\phantom{}`

```
\begin{minipage}[1.0\textwidth]
\phantom{This is some secret content.}
\end{minipage}
```

The following declaration gives me error since the curly parenthesis doesn't match up

```
\newenvironment{redacted}
    {
        \begin{minipage}[1.0\textwidth]
        \phantom{
    }
    {
        }
        \end{minipage}
    }
```

Are there any ways to achieve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `comment` package and its `comment` environment?

Comment: I'm aware of the `comment` environment. However, `phantom`, to my understanding, leaves empty spaces in the text area while `comment` doesn't.

Comment: You have to extract the contents first and then add it to phantom. For example save the minipage in a box (lrbox env, wrapped around the minipage), then use the box inside phantom in the end of the env definition. Generally you cannot span a macro over a begin end env

Answer (score 9):

I believe you want something like this. Note that I put the `minipage` inside `\phantom` and not the other way around, because when called in a non-math mode, `\phantom` typesets its argument in restricted horizontal mode (LR-mode in LaTeX terms), therefore using `\phantom{\BODY}` would always get you one (possibly extremely long) line.

`\BODY` collects the body of the environment declared with `\NewEnviron`. This macro comes from the very convenient `environ` package.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewEnviron{redacted}{%
  \par\noindent
  \phantom{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \BODY
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
  \par
}

\begin{document}

Before.

\begin{redacted}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{redacted}

After.

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

Similar to frougon's answer, another option is to use the `xparse` package with its `b` argument type, which first scans the environment body such that it can be used as a normal parameter in the environment definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{redacted}{b}{%
}{%
    \phantom{%
        \begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}%
        #1%
        \end{minipage}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{redacted}
This is\\
some\\
secret content.
\end{redacted}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]